# Codeigniter 4 filling div with a view from controller

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I want to fill a div from my controller that called with ajax for my onchange, but I can't make it work, I think the problem is in the function in the controller that I called.

I try using the return view and else but nothing works, I try using the setBody but it can't provide for my looping for the table.

Here is the **div** that I want to fill in :

```
<div id="tableCont"></div>
```

Here is my script in my **myscript.js** :

```
function call_user_menu ()
{
    $.ajax({            
     type: 'GET',
     url: 'http://localhost:8080/menumanagement/formMenuUser',
     dataType: 'html',
     success: function (html) {
        $("#tableCont").empty();
        $("#tableCont").html(html);
                            
        },
        error: function(){
          Swal.fire({
          title: 'Menu Data failed to load!',
          text: "",
          icon: 'warning',
          confirmButtonColor: '#d33',
          cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
          })        
        },
    });
    
}
```

Here is my function in my **Controller** :

```
public function formMenuUser()
{
    //the default return view :
    return view('menu_form-menu-user.php');

    //what should I write here to call the view to fill the div?
    //can I use the setBody? but I can't use my foreach there

}
```

I really appreciate any help that can provide. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to supply the data to build your loop in that method, and the HTML that builds out the table in the view.

Make sure you're calling the Model at the top:

```
use App\Models\FormMenuUserModel;
```

IE: Try this method..

```
public function formMenuUser()
{
    $getMenuUserItems       = (new FormMenuUserModel)->findAll();
    $data = [
        'title'             => 'View Form',
        'menuItems'         =>  $getMenuUserItems
    ];
    // uncomment the line below to make sure it is returning the data you want
    // echo '<pre>';print_r($data);echo '</pre>';die;
    return view('menu_form-menu-user', $data);
}
```

And in your menu_form-menu-user view, add your forloop to display the menu table how you want..

```
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
<?php foreach ($menuItems as $row) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="<?= site_url($row['link']); ?>"><?= $row['title'] ?></a></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the view like this.

```
$html = view('menu_form-menu-user')->render();
return $this->response->setBody($html);
```

Read - [Working with the Response](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/outgoing/response.html#working-with-the-response)

Comment: Thanks for the response @Abdulla , but when I try that, the view is in error state, it says : "Expected type 'object'. Found 'string'". Maybe because of the render() ?

Comment: remove `render` and try. check the value of `$html` before pass it. Use `print_r($html)` die;`

Comment: it just go into the error function that popup, not printing the value